# Is it possible to have more than just one backup when editing text files?

Tags: backup, editors

`Gedit` and `medit` are two text editors that I know of that allow me to save a backup. So, if I create a file called `temp.txt` the next time I edit it and then save it, I'll have a backup called `temp.txt~`.

My question is this: is there a text editor that allows me to have backups named in a serial fashion so that I can have more than just the one backup in case I want to go back to the file as it existed a few revisions ago?   For example, I'd have `temp.txt` as the latest version and `temp.bak.1`, `temp.bak.2`, etc.?

If that is not possible, is there some script that will automatically rename a backup each time it is created so that serial versions are retained? Even a `temp.timestamp.txt` would be great.

(I don't mind a solution using `nano` as the text editor.)

---

I should clarify that I'm not a coder or programmer. I just want to have previous versions of text files that I edit. These text files maybe `.css` or `.rc` or `.svg` files that form part of a theme. So if I edit some aspect of a theme's file, I can go back a bit in case I don't like a change I made.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use any VCS? Also you can write simple script based on sleep/at/cron/etc (or even inotify) which will do a lot of copies. Also you can configure syslogd to do this.

Comment: Could you please expand "VCS"?

Comment: VCS - version control system (like mercurial, git and so on). But I think, `syslogd` really can help you.

Comment: I should have made clear I'm quite new to all this and don't know scripting but I'll take a look and see if I can figure out how to do so.

Comment: Read about `syslog-ng`: you can run it by `cron` and it will automatically rotate your backups. Another way is VCS, for example, you can run by `cron` or by `at` something like `hg commit -m "rotation"` and last version of file will be saved in mercurial tree (later you can watch all versions and restore any of them). If you will setup mercurial server, then you'll be able to store your backups on it by `hg push` and restore them anywhere by `hg pull`.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question. I'm afraid your suggestions are way beyond my competence :(

Comment: @Eddy_Em Can you post it as an answer? Version control is the only solution to such a question.

Comment: @vasa1 Mercurial works really, really easy for basic back-up. It can be your competence in 15 minutes :)

Comment: I'm not an IT guy, I'll have to do a lot of reading first but I'll give it a try!

Comment: You don't need to know everything: `hg init`, `hg add`, `hg commit` and `hg revert` are possibly enough. If you have it installed already, you can type `hg help command` to find the help that you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way to use mercurial for version control.
First install it.

To configure mercurial make a file `~/.hgrc` with next content:

```
[ui]
username = Your name <your mail>
verbose = True
```

If you use some mercurial servers, you can add more info to this file (read `man hgrc`).

After that `cd` to directory with your text files. For example:

```
> cd /tmp
> mkdir data && cd data
> cat > text_file.txt
Hello, this is a file.
```

You can add also any number of files.
After we must init mercurial:

```
> hg init
```

By default there's no files still, so we must to say mercurial, that we want to include all:

```
> hg st
? text_file.txt
> hg add    
adding text_file.txt
> hg st
A text_file.txt
```

Now we make do simple commit:

```
> hg comm -m 'first run'
text_file.txt
committed changeset 0:87e90c949984
```

Now do some fixes and see difference:

```
> cat >> text_file.txt 
Add one line.
> hg diff
diff -r 87e90c949984 text_file.txt
--- a/text_file.txt Mon Apr 01 12:52:14 2013 +0400
+++ b/text_file.txt Mon Apr 01 12:53:47 2013 +0400
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
 Hello, this is a file.
+Add one line.
```

Now make another commit, after watch `hg log`: you will see both commits.

To return to first commit just do so:

```
> hg upd -r 0:87e90c949984
resolving manifests
getting text_file.txt
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
> cat text_file.txt 
Hello, this is a file.
```

You see: a file is old.

Now restore last file:

```
> hg upd                  
resolving manifests
getting text_file.txt
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
> cat text_file.txt 
Hello, this is a file.
Add one line.
```

Also you may do a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  hg commit -m "commit: $(date)"
  sleep 60
done
```

Run it when you start to edit your file, and it will check for changes every minute, if there was changes, mercurial will make new commit.
Also, as I've mention in comments, you can use `at` or `cron` for autocommits.

Comment: I've installed `mercurial` via Synaptic. I did the steps until `hg comm -m 'first run'`. At this point I got `abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")`. I'm the only user of my computer. Anyway, I'll take a look at `hg help config`.

Comment: Sorry, I forget about is (as my mercurial was configured a long time ago). Make fix.

Answer (score 2):

I second the recommendation to use [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). It's a lot more flexible and more reliable than keeping backup files around, and it's easy to set up.

Nonetheless, if you want fine control over backup files (and over many other things), you can use Emacs. Set the [`version-control`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html#Backup-Names) variable to `t` to make numbered backups and not just keep one backup file per session (put `(setq version-control t)` in your `~/.emacs`). Press `C-u C-x C-s` instead of just `C-x C-s` when you want to create a new backup.

Another approach is to use a filesystem that makes the backups for you, regardless of whether the application knows anything about backups. [CopyFS](http://n0x.org/copyfs/) creates such a filesystem on top of any directory tree.

Answer (score 1):

Geany comes with a suitable plugin as well. I'm using Geany 1.23.1 on Lubuntu 13.10. Clicking on *Tools*, *Plugin Manager* shows this:

[image: Plugin Manager dialog]

In here, one can tick `Save Actions` and then, in *Edit*, *Plugin Preferences*, one can set up how the backups are to be saved:

[image: Save Actions dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a [doublesave](https://code.google.com/p/double-save-gedit/) plugin for gEdit. Although it uses a timestamp instead of an incrementing number.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but you can achieve unique backup functionality in `nano` (at least in the current Debian version 2.2.6) using the `-B` and `-C` flags.

From the Debian man page:

```
   -B (--backup)
          When saving a file, back up the previous version of it to the  current  filename
          suffixed with a ~.

   -C dir (--backupdir=dir)
          Set  the  directory  where  nano  puts  unique  backup files if file backups are
          enabled.
```

To make this default, create a bash alias for nano including the flags, and put it where appropriate (adding the line below to `/home/username/.bash_aliases` works for me):

```
alias nano='nano -BC /home/username/.nano_backups'
```

Which will yield backups in the specified directory like:

```
$ ls /home/username/.nano_backups
!home!username!.bash_aliases~
!home!username!.bash_aliases~.1
!home!username!.bash_aliases~.10
!home!username!.bash_aliases~.11
!home!username!.bash_aliases~.12
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

With vv you can have up to 100 backup files.
vv is an addon tool for any editor and can save, recover, list, etc hidden backups, fully automatic.

See http://fex.belwue.de/fstools/vv.html